# ArcSDE for PostgreSQL installation

Tags: arcgis-server, postgis, enterprise-geodatabase, postgresql, centos

I am trying to install ArcSDE 10 for PostgreSQL in CentOS. I tried doing that but am stuck with same errors repeatedly and am thinking of giving one more shot from the scratch. I just want to make sure the versions/releases before I start over again. I am thinking of using CentOS 5.4 (for i686 architecture), PostgreSQL 8.3.8/8.4.1, PostGIS 1.4.0 and ArcSDE 10. Please let me know if I have to change any version/releases of any software.

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure that you know that CentOS isn't a supported platform (not that support on 'nix platforms has ever been very useful)  http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/arcgis-server-server-requirements#SupportedPlatforms

Comment: Actually, this is the better URL.  Because ArcSDE is ArcGIS Server, except that it really isn't...  http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcsde/10.0/postgresql-system-requirements

Answer (score 2):

@troublemaker, I do have that setup, except using CentOS 5.5, and postgres 8.3.8.  Additionally, I have GEOS 3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2 and PROJ-4.7.1.  I am able to access the database through ArcCatalog, load data and access it through ArcMap.  I'm sorry I don't remember the specifics on getting SDE running on it.  Although I am running 10, I found the 9.3 documentation mostly helpful.  http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/geodatabase/pdf/install_gd_postgresql.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[10 postgres support](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcsde/10.0/postgresql-system-requirements)
I didn't answer with what you have to do.
The link provides direction on the software stack that "is" supported.
I am certain that there are unsupported stacks running successfully.
However outside of "supported", help would have to come from someone who has the same, (such as mfrancis).
So in my opinion that is the answer you should choose.

Comment: If you're referring to the minimum requirements ("ArcSDE for PostgreSQL is not supported on Red Hat 4"), then this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have read somewhere that CentOS and RHEL 5 are identical, and CentOS uses the same source files that RHEL uses. Doesn't that mean we can replace RHEL with CentOS?

Comment: Yes, which is why I _think_ that link was posted.